# interpolate data by a few columns

Tags: r

I have a large data frame with meteorological conditions at different locations (column radar_id), time (column date) and heights (column hgt).

I need to interpolate the data of each parameter (temp,u,v...) to a specific height (500 m above the ground for each radar- altitude_500 column) separately for each location (radar_id) and date.

I tried to do the approx command in dplyr pipes or splitting the data frame but it didn't work for me...

example of part of my data frame:

```
head (example)

radar_id date        temp      u      v   hgt     W wind_ang temp_diff      tw altitude_500
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Dagan    2014-03-02  18.8 -6.00   4.80     77  7.68    129.       5.    -3.33           547
2 Dagan    2014-03-02  17.6 -2.40   9.30    742  9.60    166.       6     -9.20           547
3 Dagan    2014-03-02  16.2  3.10  15.4    1463 15.7    -169.       5.80 -10.4            547
4 Dagan    2014-03-03  16.2  0.900 -0.500    96  1.03    -60.9     -2.6   -0.971          547
5 Dagan    2014-03-03  13.0  3.10  -0.500   754  3.14    -80.8     -4.6   -2.39           547
6 Dagan    2014-03-03  10.8  8.10   4.10   1462  9.08   -117.      -5.30  -5.01           547
```

I want to get a column with the y values from the approx command for each parameter (the x values are the height -hgt),at a specific height (by the altitude_500 column), after the data frame is grouped by radar_id and date .

Comment: Will there only be one `altitude_500` value for each `radar_id`-`date` pair?

Comment: Yes,
Thanks a lot!
Your solution works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. First, I define the data.

```r
# Data
df <- read.table(text = "radar_id date        temp      u      v   hgt     W wind_ang temp_diff      tw altitude_500
1 Dagan    2014-03-02  18.8 -6.00   4.80     77  7.68    129.       5.    -3.33           547
2 Dagan    2014-03-02  17.6 -2.40   9.30    742  9.60    166.       6     -9.20           547
3 Dagan    2014-03-02  16.2  3.10  15.4    1463 15.7    -169.       5.80 -10.4            547
4 Dagan    2014-03-03  16.2  0.900 -0.500    96  1.03    -60.9     -2.6   -0.971          547
5 Dagan    2014-03-03  13.0  3.10  -0.500   754  3.14    -80.8     -4.6   -2.39           547
6 Dagan    2014-03-03  10.8  8.10   4.10   1462  9.08   -117.      -5.30  -5.01           547")
```

Then, I load the `dplyr` package.

```r
# Load library
library(dplyr)
```

Finally, I group by both `radar_id` and `date` and perform a linear interpolation using `approx` to get the value at `altitude_500` m for each column (except the grouping variables and `hgt`).

```r
# Group then summarise
df %>% 
  group_by(radar_id, date) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-hgt), ~approx(hgt, ., xout = first(altitude_500))$y)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#> # Groups:   radar_id [1]
#>   radar_id date   temp     u     v     W wind_ang temp_diff    tw
#>   <fct>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Dagan    2014~  18.0 -3.46  7.98  9.04    155.       5.71 -7.48
#> 2 Dagan    2014~  14.0  2.41 -0.5   2.48    -74.5     -3.97 -1.94
#> # ... with 1 more variable: altitude_500 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This assumes that there is only one value of `altitude_500` for each `radar_id` -`date` pair.